# Angular - Include models getters & setters וn Http Requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular 6 spa and when I send a model with private members wrapped with public setter and getter to the server the request body (JSON) includes the private members (starting with '_' code convention) and doesn't serialize the getter and setters.
I added an interceptor to solve this, but since this is a global solution I want to ensure it won't have any side effects.

```js
export class PrivatePropertiesGettersOverrideInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
    const isCUDRequest = ['POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'].indexOf(request.method) > -1;

    if (isCUDRequest) {
      // If has private members with getters we will use the getter value
      const clone = this._deepCloneWithOverrides(request.body);
      request = request.clone({
        body: clone
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  private _deepCloneWithOverrides(object: any): Object {
    if (object == null || typeof object !== 'object' || object instanceof Date || object instanceof String ) {
      return object;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
      return object.map(o => this._deepCloneWithOverrides(o));
    }

    return Object.keys(object).reduce((newObj, prop) => {
      const newPropName = prop.startsWith('_') ? prop.slice(1, prop.length) : prop;
      newObj[newPropName] = this._deepCloneWithOverrides(object[newPropName]) || this._deepCloneWithOverrides(object[prop]);
      return newObj;
    }, {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` only serializes enumerable properties. You can make a getter enumerable by using `Object.defineProperty`:

```
constructor() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', {
    get: () => this._foo,
    set: value => this._foo = value,
    enumerable: true
  });
}
```